# How to find a record that is associated to only certain other record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am searching for users in my system who are associated to *only* a specific list of reports.

Each user can be associated to many different reports. I have three reports that I need to treat differently than others. Let's say they have ids of 1, 2, and 3.

I tried this:

```
User.joins(:user_reports).where(active: true, user_reports: {report_id: [1,2,3]})
```

This is close, but it finds users who are associated to the reports I am looking for, but it also finds those who are associated to those reports *and other reports as well*.

How do I find those users who are associated to *only* those specific reports, or any combination thereof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will help:

```
disallowed_user_ids = UserReport.
                      where("report_id NOT IN (?)", report_ids).
                      pluck("DISTINCT user_id")

User.
joins(:reports).
where("users.id NOT IN (?)", disallowed_user_ids).
group("users.id")
```

Might also be possible with an ugly subquery:

```
User.
joins(:reports).
where("users.id NOT IN (
  SELECT user_id FROM user_reports WHERE report_id IN (?)
)", report_ids).
group("users.id")
```

If each user in your DB has at least one report, then you can drop the `joins` and `group`.

**Update:**

The following is also an option:

```
report_ids_str = report_ids.join(',')

User.
select("COUNT(r2.id) AS r2c, #{User.column_names.join(',')}").
joins("INNER JOIN reports AS r1 ON (
  r1.user_id = users.id AND r1.id IN (#{report_ids_str}))").
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN reports AS r2 ON (
  r2.user_id = users.id AND r2.id NOT IN (#{report_ids_str}))").
group("users.id").
where("r2c = 0")
```

You might be able to replace the `select` and `where` with a `having("COUNT(r2.id) = 0")`.

Comment: I think my question may have been slightly ambiguous. This appears to find only those users that are associated to one of those reports. I need to find users who are associated to any combination of those reports. If a user is associated to report 1, it should return them. If they are associated to 1 and 2, it should return them. If a user is associated to 1, 2 and 5, it should NOT return them.

Comment: Yeah, that clarifies things. I've updated my answer. It spans multiple queries though. But it's still better than a no-solution. =/

Comment: I'm not concerned about the multiple queries, this is a one-off. Works like a charm, thanks

Comment: I see. I've now added a single-query, double-join solution, just in case.